# Fetch Mysql Results into serialized data

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have this table:

```
| id | related_id |
| 1  | 100        |
| 1  | 200        |
| 1  | 300        |
| 2  | 400        |
| 2  | 500        |
| 2  | 600        |
```

I need to retrieve serialized data as:

```
 a:3:{i:1;s:3:"100";i:2;s:3:"200";i:3;s:3:"300";}
```

Query

```
 SELECT id, related_id from mytable where id = 1;
```

I'm trying to get this using 'while'

```
$result = $link->query($query);
$item   = array();

while($f = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $id = $f['id'];
  if ($id == $f['id']){
    $item[] = $f['related_id'];
  }
  print serialize($item);
  break; // for test
}
```

SOLUTION that works for me (provided by Erwin - Thanks!)

```
$item = array();
while($f = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id = $f['id'];
  if (!array_key_exists($id, $item)) {
    $item[$id] = [1 => $f['related_id']];
  } else {
    $item[$id][] = $f['related_id'];
  }
}
foreach ($item as $value) {
  print serialize($value) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is the logic your are looking for to get as results ?

Comment: So what does your attempt result in? Where does it go wrong? Btw, you're expected output is two arrays, not one.

Comment: This is probably a typo: `if ($id = $f['id'])`. `=` sets a variable, `==` does a loose comparison and `===` does a strict comparison (data type must match). However, that if-statement is useless since you're setting the variable above it. Basically you're saying: "Set $id as x" and on the next row: "Check if $id is x". Obviously it will be x since you've just set it to x.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson right, I change the code to if ($id == $f['id']). But I'm keep getting one item of data. I multiples arrays, each one with your id and related ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect first each related_id and store to id array with your `while loop`. Then print each using `foreach`.

```
$item = array();
while($f = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $f['id'];
    if (!array_key_exists($id, $item)) {      // create id array if not exist
        $item[$id] = [1 => $f['related_id']]; // To start with index 1
    } else {
        $item[$id][] = $f['related_id'];      // Push each new related_id
    }
}

foreach ($item as $value) {
    print serialize($value); // Print each serialized
    echo '<br>';             // New line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is something like this:

```
$result = $link->query($query);
$items   = array();

while($f = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $id = $f['id'];
  if(!isset($items[$id])) {
     $items[$id] = array();
  }
  $items[$id][] = $f['related_id'];
}

foreach($items as $item) {
  print serialize($item);
}
```

For your serialized string, you have to work with an array with related_id in the second layer. The first layer is to save all related_id in an array with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You have 6 rows, 3 have id 1 and 3 have id 2. You are specifying that you want to use these ids as array keys so you will end up with 2 arrays, each holding 3 values.

If you want each row in its own array you do this:

```
while($f = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $item[] = array($f['id'] => $f['related_id']);
  }
```